# Center movieclip at mouse position

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, animation, actionscript, air

I am using Action Script 3.0 to animate an instance (MovieClip class) to follow the mouse positron the thing is, the left corner of the instance follows the mouse courser. Now there is a cross on the to left corner and my guess would be that the mouse follows that cross, but i can not change the position of the cross within the instance/ original object.
Does anyone know how to make the center of that instance follow the mouse cursor? 
Thank You all for ANY help on that topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code.

```
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.events.Event;


var easing:Number = .25;                    // inching coefficient

var sp:Shape = super.addChild(new Shape()) as Shape;        // draw circle
sp.graphics.beginFill(0x0,.6);
sp.graphics.drawCircle(40,40,40);

sp.x = super.stage.stageWidth - sp.width >> 1;
sp.y = super.stage.stageHeight - sp.height >> 1;

super.stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update, false, 0, true);

function update(e:Event):void
{
    var targetX:int = super.stage.mouseX - (sp.width >> 1);
    var targetY:int = super.stage.mouseY - (sp.height >> 1);

    sp.x += (targetX - sp.x) * easing;
    sp.y += (targetY - sp.y) * easing;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:
Dont change the position of the registrationpoint (the cross). Change the contents of the movieclip to align with the center position. Try it and you will understand.

Solution 2:
Move your instance with an offset. Something like this.

```
myInstance.x = mouseX - (myInstance.width * 0.5);
myInstance.y = mouseY - (myInstance.height * 0.5);
```

Comment: When you make the offset (solution 2), can you make i using pixels (like 20 pixels across t X axis, And 50 down the Y axis)?                    Thanks For the Quick answer anyway :D

Comment: You can do whatever you want. :)